# Wont show or find image

Tags: java, eclipse, image, path

Example:

```
File imageCheck = new File("picture.gif");
    if(imageCheck.exists()) 
        System.out.println("Image file found!");
    else 
        System.out.println("Image file not found!");
```

Image is in source directory and it wont show it on a button or on a label. I am working in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in the project directory, not the source directory.